# How do I fix "CORRUPTION WARNING in SBCL"

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm encountering a worrying error in SBCL -- I suspect that it arises from pilot error, and would love some tips if you have them!

Here is the error:

```
Memory fault at 0x52 (pc=0x52cffa19 [code 0x52cff6d0+0x349 ID 0x86a2], fp=0x7ff37f29f6d0, sp=0x7ff37f29f698) tid 0x7ff38ca82180
The integrity of this image is possibly compromised.
Continuing with fingers crossed.
"derp" 
debugger invoked on a SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1000510083}>:
  Unhandled memory fault at #x52.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(HMAKER-II)
   source: (LIST (CAR (CDR (CDR IENTRY))))
```

Here is the code that I'm running. It is a few connected subroutines in a larger program. The overall program takes structured text input and adds to a hash table, this subroutine takes the contents of the table and is intended to organize it back into a single structured output in the same form as the input (it's not quite finished, I've only got as far as creating a new table with modified data in order to create a well-formed output).

I'm conscious that my code is messy and can be improved -- I would appreciate pointers on improving it, but my main goal is first to fix the error before focusing in better and more efficient code.

Here you go:

```
(defun hmaker-launcher ()
   (setf table-entries-for-hmaker (alexandria:hash-table-alist etable))
   (hmaker))
   
(defun hmaker ()
   (if (equal table-entries-for-hmaker nil)
      (progn
         (setf sorted-list-of-ientries (sort (alexandria:hash-table-alist itable)  #'> :key #'third))
         (hmaker-II)))
   (setf table-entry-for-hmaker (car table-entries-for-hmaker))
   (setf entry-name-for-hmaker (car table-entry-for-hmaker))
   (setf entry-number (car (reverse table-entry-for-hmaker)))
   (setf processed-entry-for-hmaker (cdr (reverse (cdr (cdr (reverse table-entry-for-hmaker))))))

   (if (equal entry-number 8)
      (progn
      (setf (gethash entry-name-for-hmaker itable) (list '8 (length (car processed-entry-for-hmaker)) processed-entry-for-hmaker))
      )
      )
     
   (if (equal entry-number 9)
      (progn
      (setf number-of-elements (list-length processed-entry-for-hmaker))
         (setf (gethash entry-name-for-hmaker itable) (list '9 number-of-elements processed-entry-for-hmaker))
   ))
         
   (setf table-entries-for-hmaker (cdr table-entries-for-hmaker))
   (hmaker)
   )
   
(defun hmaker-II ()

   (if (equal sorted-list-of-ientries nil)
      (inputter))
   (setf ientry (car sorted-list-of-ientries))
   (if (equal '9 (car (cdr ientry)))
      (progn
         (setf complexity-atom (list (car (cdr (cdr ientry)))))
         (setf hmaker-complexity-list (append hmaker-complexity-list complexity-atom))
         (setf (nth hmaker-recursion-counter complexity-adder) (+ (car (cdr (cdr identry))) (nth hmaker-recursion-counter complexity-adder)))
         (setf (second (gethash (car ientry) itable)) complexity-adder)
         (setf rel-parts (cdr (cdr (cdr ientry))))
         (push "padding" rel-parts)
         (hmaker-III rel-parts)
         )
         
         
(defun hmaker-III (parts)
   (setf parts (cdr parts))
   (if (equal parts nil)
       (setf sorted-list-of-ientries (cdr sorted-list-of-ientries))
       (hmaker-II)
       )
   (setf part-in-question (car parts))
   (if (equal '9 (car (cdr (part-in-question))))
      (progn
         (setf hmaker-recursion-counter (+ hmaker-recursion-counter 1))
         (setf (nth hmaker-recursion-counter complexity-adder) (+ (car (cdr (gethash part-in-question)) (nth hmaker-recursion-counter complexity-adder))))
         (setf sub-parts (cdr (cdr (gethash part-in-question itable))))
         (hmaker-III sub-parts)
      )
      (progn
         (hmaker-III parts))
         )
         )
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you compiling with low "safety" values? `(sb-ext:describe-compiler-policy)` can tell you that if you don't know. Corruption warnings etc. means it is possible that there is some type error somewhere, but the runtime doesn't check it properly because the code is compiled with unsafe policies; If that's the case I suggest setting "debug" and "safety" to 3 first to debug the code

Comment: You can probably achieve better performance by using local variables (using let), because here your setf are touching global bindings (this is not a conforming program btw, unless you defvar them before)

Comment: The parentheses are not balanced. Your code thus looks strange.

Comment: There are a bunch of undeclared variables.

Comment: If you want the best advice from the community, it would help to know about the environment and software version, additionally to a working piece of code, so that it can be reproduced by other people.